# Change the datetime format for a datatable

Tags: datetime, datagrid, datatable

i have a form that can connect to either oracle,sql or access. i am binding a datagrid to a datatable which contains 3 datetime values. one of this datacolumn is filled by a function which fills the column in the format `dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`. but the other 2 columns are not displayed in the same format. since the db can be any of the 3, i cant mentioned the formatting in the common query used to fill the datatable. how can i have the other 2 columns also in the format `dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss`. my .net version is 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

For rest of two column parse them in the same format as first one :
use TryParseExact method for parsing of date,

```
    DateTime.TryParseExact(dateValue, pattern, null, 
DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
```

for more pattern check this :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

first format your string, try like this:

```
DateTime dt=Convert.toDateTime(dr["StartTime"]);

//String.Format("{0:F}", dt);//for full datetime pattern
```

then try it like

```
dt.toString("F");
```

Comment: if( DateTime.TryParseExact(dr["StartTime"].ToString(), "dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dtStartTime))
                         dr["StartTime"]=dtStartTime;
i tried like this. the value of dr["starttime"] is "10/10/2011 11:15:08 AM" .. but the tryparseexact returned false value

Comment: instead of writing code in comment ..you can edit your question navya.

Comment: also the dtstarttime value was datetime.min value

Comment: Pranav, i mentioned the code just to show you that i have tried the method you mentioned. pls do let me know if i have to add anything to the above mentioned code.

Comment: build error :"No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments"

Comment: still it is returning false.   :(